# Read/Write issues, SATA PCI-E Addon

Tags: raid, sata

I'm rather new to Ubuntu/Linux, and it's been an education experience so far. However I've been struggling with an issue I've been unable to overcome.

I'm getting an issue that causes freezing/hanging during read/writing to a hard disk. Not the system hanging, just the data transfer or anything being ran on the HDD's affected.

My HDD configuration is as follows:
120GB SSD, partitioned 1 Windows 10 (legacy/gaming requirements), partition 2 Ubuntu 15 64bit (minimalist install) Gnome Desktop, Partition 3 is Swap. Boot loader is using Grub 2.
Then I have a RAID 5 configuration consisting of 6 x 2TB (7200rpm) SATA III Drives. This was configured using mdadm post installation.

Read/Write on the SSD seems to be fine, but more apparent on the RAID sector. When data is being transferred it will have no HDD activity for around 5-10 seconds and then a burst of speed (around 120MB/s for 5-10 seconds) then back to a hang.

PCI-E SATA: http://www.startech.com/uk/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards/2-Port-PCI-Express-SATA-6-Gbps-Controller-Card~PEXSAT32

This software RAID is using a small RAID controller to attach all drives. The controller is just being used for SATA port expansion and not doing any stripping it's self. I connected a separate HDD to the controller and that seems to demonstrate the same symptoms. The SSD connected to the mainboard is working fine.

Before switching to Linux as my primary OS, I had the same configuration through Windows, which works fine. To confirm, I've tested back in this and read my separate drive using ext2fsd. Which worked fine.

To check, I've ran short HDD tests on all drives and they all passed with no bad sectors. The Health section in the Disks utility shows all healthy also.

I've also tried changing the I/O scheduler from information online, but doesn't make a difference. Also I've checked to ensure swap is active from other information.

I think it is related, during the boot, after GRUB. It will hang for a while on a blank screen with an underscore flashing at the top right.
It then shows the error: `ata5: Softreset failed (device not ready).`
It then shows that it's giving up and goes straight to the Gnome display manager login.

I found where I check logs and the Kern.log is full of this:

```
Oct 22 22:47:17 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18896.613896] ata7.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct 22 22:47:17 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18896.613899] ata7: hard resetting link
Oct 22 22:47:18 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18897.089597] ata7: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Oct 22 22:47:18 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18897.133592] ata7.00: configured for UDMA/33
Oct 22 22:47:18 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18897.133598] ata7.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Oct 22 22:47:18 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18897.133604] ata7: EH complete
Oct 22 22:47:23 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18902.196603] ata7: illegal qc_active transition (00000002->00000003)
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.489847] ata7.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.489851] ata7.00: failed command: READ DMA
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.489855] ata7.00: cmd c8/00:08:90:6f:21/00:00:00:00:00/ea tag 1 dma 4096 in
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.489855]          res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.489856] ata7.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.489859] ata7: hard resetting link
Oct 22 22:47:53 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18932.969484] ata7: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Oct 22 22:47:54 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18933.013500] ata7.00: configured for UDMA/33
Oct 22 22:47:54 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18933.013506] ata7.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Oct 22 22:47:54 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18933.013512] ata7: EH complete
Oct 22 22:48:15 lightwrath-desktop kernel: [18954.650783] ata9: illegal qc_active transition (00000080->000000c0)
```

I know there's a lot of information here but I thought I'd provide as much as I know to diagnose the issue.
Any feedback or assistance would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you, LightWrath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my above issue by reseating the PCI-E SATA Card. Unsure why Windows didn't have the same issue but I have noticed that data transfer speeds are much faster in Linux then Windows. Maybe due to differences in how it's handled or a benefit over NTFS?

Thank you.

(I'm unable to accept my own answer to close the topic)

Comment: You will be able to accept in a few days...  (I voted to close as "Problem went away all by itself" asit doesn't seem to be an Ubuntu but a HW issue...)